# Python pandas dataframe find value using expression

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

From [this tutorial](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/01%20-%20Lesson.ipynb), the author used:

```
names = ['Bob','Jessica','Mary','John','Mel']
births = [968, 155, 77, 578, 973]
# Name associated with the maximum value
MaxName = df['Names'][df['Births'] == df['Births'].max()].values ## what does the == means?
```

What is it called? And is it only for pandas?

Comment: `==` is used throughout Python to test whether two objects are equal. If you haven't encountered it yet you might want to look at general Python tutorials rather than jumping straight in to a pandas tutorial which assumes some general Python knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That represents any of the elements in 'Names' where that condition is true. It's called boolean indexing, and can be found here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing